# H2 Database Function Alias access another function

Tags: tcp, alias, h2

The problem is, after running server over TCP and creating the alias function SLIDEWINDOW
for the class timeframe, I call the alias slidewindow. But from within this function, I have to query the table (any table) to get some necessary information. When I connect again, the server and application hangs.

CODE:

```
public class TimeFrame { 
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://MYIP:9092/~/test", "sa", "");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

    //Setup Table
    stat.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS timeframe");
    stat.execute("CREATE TABLE timeframe (last_updated TIMESTAMP, ip int");
    stat.execute("CREATE ALIAS IF NOT EXISTS SLIDEWINDOW FOR \"h2TimeFrame.TimeFrame.slidewindow\" ");
} 
}
```

What if I want to access the read a table from SLIDEWINDOW function?

```
public static void slideWindow(String ip){
     ...
     Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:h2:tcp://MYIP:9092/~/test", "sa", "");
     Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
     res = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM timeframe  where ip = '" + ips + "' limit 1 ");
     ... 
}
```

Q1. Can I do that from alias?

Q2. The application hangs when I call the alias "SELECT SLIDEWINDOW('127.0.0.1')" either from H2 server web console or from java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out. For the alias, the java functions's first argument can be a "Connection", which will pass handler to the established connection.

**Q1. Can I do that from alias?**

I should not establish a connection again to the database from Alias.

**Q2. The application hangs when I call the alias "SELECT SLIDEWINDOW('127.0.0.1')" either from H2 server web console or from java application?**

I solved it by passing "Connection" as the first argument and rest as they were before. like

```
public static void slideWindow(Connection conn, String ip){
 ...
 //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:h2:tcp://MYIP:9092/~/test", "sa", "");
 Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
 res = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM timeframe  where ip = '" + ips + "' limit 1 ");
 ...
```

}

Comment: Another solution is to use the special JDBC URL `jdbc:default:connection` inside the function, meaning `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection");`